# How to get src attribute value after a checkbox click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox with an image replacement on top of it. What I am trying to do is to click on the checkbox and get the src attribute value of the image and place it inside a textarea.

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <input type="checkbox" name="thing_5" value="valuable" id="thing_5">
  <label for="thing_5">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/U.S._Marines_in_Operation_Allen_Brook_(Vietnam_War)_001.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
<textarea id='txtarea'></textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
var tempValue = '';
$('.thumbnail :checkbox').change(function() {
    tempValue += $(this).nextAll("img").attr("src");
    $('textarea').html(tempValue);        
});
```

**CSS**

```
textarea{width:100%;height:200px;}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: #999;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    border: 10px solid grey;
    padding: 0;
}
```

AT the moment I get `undefined` inside the `textarea`.

**JsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/vWFQQ/33/

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vWFQQ/39/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.nextAll()` won't work because, it is inside the `<label>`. You need to use `.next()` and `.find()`:

```
tempValue += $(this).next("label").find("img").attr("src");
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tempValue = '';
  $('.thumbnail :checkbox').change(function() {
    tempValue += $(this).next("label").find("img").attr("src");
    $('textarea').html(tempValue);
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  border: 10px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <input type="checkbox" name="thing_5" value="valuable" id="thing_5">
  <label for="thing_5">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/U.S._Marines_in_Operation_Allen_Brook_(Vietnam_War)_001.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
<textarea id='txtarea'></textarea>
```

Comment: hey thanks, I will accept it in a minute. Is it there anyway I can add/remove the checked item from the textarea? What if I have more images/checkboxes for example http://jsfiddle.net/vWFQQ/40/

Comment: @rob.m You might need to redo the whole loop. That's the best way. Do you want a different solution?

Comment: yeah maybe this isn't the best solution, if you could help i'd be thankful

Comment: @rob.m Doing it. Few mins.